# Sublists in a 2D List, Referencing

Tags: java, reference, sublist

I have a 2D List of objects. I'm trying to access a list and replace it with a sublist of itself. I made up a simple example below, I want to replace dList.get(0) with dList.get(0).subList(1,3). I use a reference variable, which updates the values in the original list, but the subList is not getting updated. I`m a bit new to this, any help in the form of examples, explanations and directing me documentation is appreciated.

```
List<List<Double>> dList = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
/**
* Initialize, the 2D List with some values
*/
protected void init() {
    List<Double> d = new ArrayList<Double>();
    d.add(1.0);
    d.add(2.0);
    d.add(3.0);
    d.add(4.0);
    d.add(5.0);
    dList.add(d);
}

/**
 * Check if the subList update works.
 */
protected void check() {
    List<Double> tmp = dList.get(0); //get the reference into a temporary variable
    tmp = tmp.subList(1, 3);    //get the sublist, in the end the original list dList.get(0) should be this.
    tmp.set(0, 4.5);  //reference works, the  dList.get(0) values get updated
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(tmp.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("....Original 2D List Values....");
    for (int i = 0; i < dList.get(0).size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(dList.get(0).get(i));  // still has all the elements, and not the sublist
    }
    System.out.println("Result" + dList.get(0).size());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmp.subList()` returns a new List instance that is different from the first element of `dList`. That's why the original List was unchanged.

You need to set the first element of `dList` to refer to the sub-list you created :

```
List<Double> tmp = dList.get(0); 
tmp = tmp.subList(1, 3);    
tmp.set(0, 4.5); 
dList.set (0, tmp);
```